# Create img and p tag side by side with different sizes

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web development and I am stuck on this problem. What I am trying to do is  show a words on the left(20-30% width/ small square) and img(70-80% large square)on the right then right.Directly below it have a small img box of  with a large word box on the right.
For the life of me I can't make both the same height as well.
Sorry I'm describing it the best way I  can.
I want it to look like this website reservation and about div.
https://dribbble.com/shots/2052368-Faicco-s-Italian-Restaurant-Parallax/attachments/366053

```js
function sorry(){
 alert("This is just a example.")
}
```

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
img{
 max-width: 100%;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,p{
 margin: 0;
}
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

html{
  background: url("background.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
background-size: 100% 100%
}
#header-background{
 background: url("restaurant.jpg");
 height: 75vh;
 width: 90%;
 margin: 5% auto 0 auto ;
 background-size: cover;
 background-size: 100% 100%
}
header h3{
 float: left;
    margin: 21px 0 0 45px;
 font-family: Brush Script MT, cursive;
 font-size: 42px;
 color: white;
}
nav{
 float: right;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 right: 5%;
 top:1.5%;
}
nav ul{
 list-style-type: none;
}
nav li{
 float: left;
 text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 27px;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}
nav li:before{
 padding-right:10px;
}
#header-middle{
 width: 50%;
 margin:200px auto 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}
.rise h1{
 font-size: 50px;
 color: white;
 margin:0;
 letter-spacing: 4px;


}
.rise h2{
 font-size: 50px;
 color: white;
 margin: 0;
}
.rise{
 position: relative;
 animation-name: rise;
 animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
@keyframes rise{
 0% {bottom: -500px; opacity:-3;}
 100%{ bottom: 0px; opacity: 1; }
}
.rise2{
 position: relative;
 animation-name: rise2;
 animation-duration: 2s;
}
@keyframes rise2{
 0% {bottom:-500;opacity:-8;}
 100%{bottom:0px; opacity:1;}
}
/*Inner Content*/
#middle{
 height: 45vh;
 width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto 5% auto ;
 background-color: WhiteSmoke;
}
#inner-content-wrapper{
 width: 80%;
}
#inner-wrapper{
 position: relative;
 bottom: 35px;
 width: 50%;
 margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
}
#wrapper{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
}
#inner-content{
 width: 80%;
    object-fit: contain;
 float: left;
  display: block;
}
#inner-content img{
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height:100%;
 display: block;
}
#inner-content:first-child { 
     width: 20%;
}
#inner-content:nth-child(3){
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="food.css">
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="header-background">
    <div class="cf">
   <header >
     <h3>Taco Día Del</h3>
      <nav>
     <ul>
    <li>Shop</li>
    <li>Recipes</li>
    <li>News</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
     </ul>
       </nav>
   </header>
    </div>
     <div id="header-middle" class="rise">
   <h2>Taco Día Del</h2>
   <h1 class="rise2">Mexican Specialties</h1>
  </div>
   </div>

   <div id="wrapper">
       <div id="middle">
         <div id="inner-wrapper" class="cf">
          <div id="inner-content-wrapper" class="cf">
               <div id="inner-content" class="cf">
               <h2>Reservation</h2>
               <br>
               <p>Call us now to book a table in our restaurant. Calls must be in the same day as the reservation.</p>
                 <br>
                 <a onclick="sorry()">BOOK A TABLE</a>
             </div>
            </section>
                <div id ="inner-content" class="cf">
                 <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/73/001_Tacos_de_carnitas%2C_carne_asada_y_al_pastor.jpg/1200px-001_Tacos_de_carnitas%2C_carne_asada_y_al_pastor.jpg">
             </div>
             <!--Extra-->
                             <div id ="inner-content" class="cf">
                 <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/73/001_Tacos_de_carnitas%2C_carne_asada_y_al_pastor.jpg/1200px-001_Tacos_de_carnitas%2C_carne_asada_y_al_pastor.jpg">
             </div>
             <div id="inner-content" class="cf">
               <h2>Reservation</h2>
               <br>
               <p>Call us now to book a table in our restaurant. Calls must be in the same day as the reservation.</p>
                 <br>
                 <a onclick="sorry()">BOOK A TABLE</a>
             </div>
            </section>

          </div>
         </div>
       </div>
   </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="food.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of problems going on with your code, starting with how your have named the tags. You have used the same ID for almost all the tags. Make use of classes not ID when you want to style more than one element with the same CSS styles. And give unique ID to individual elements which you want to style differently. 
I've just taken out the relevant part of the code and modified a few things to demonstrate how the grid (Responsive) has been or could be implemented:

- Instead of using img tags, use image as a background for the div containing it.
- Use vw units to create squares with the same dimensions and that makes it responsive itself.
- For the fonts as well, you can make use of vw units like shown below.
- Float the elements to the left and right depending on their unique ID.

> Note: This is just a workaround to not implement this code from
>   scratch. But there are plenty of better and cleaner ways to achieve
>   this. You can make use of CSS grids or flexbox, etc for that matter.

```js
function sorry() {
  alert("This is just a example.")
}
```

```css
#wrapper{
width:100%;
}

.inner-content-wrapper {
width:81vw;
margin:0 auto;
}

#inner-content1,
#inner-content4 {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid gray;
}

#inner-content4{
float:right;
}

#inner-content1,
#inner-content2,
#inner-content3,
#inner-content4 {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#inner-content2 {
  width: 60vw;
  height: 20vw;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/73/001_Tacos_de_carnitas%2C_carne_asada_y_al_pastor.jpg/1200px-001_Tacos_de_carnitas%2C_carne_asada_y_al_pastor.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
  float:right;
  border:1px solid gray;
}

#inner-content3 {
float:left;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 20vw;
  border:1px solid gray;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/73/001_Tacos_de_carnitas%2C_carne_asada_y_al_pastor.jpg/1200px-001_Tacos_de_carnitas%2C_carne_asada_y_al_pastor.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="inner-wrapper" class="cf">
  <div class="inner-content-wrapper" class="cf">
    <div id="inner-content1" class="cf">
      <h2>Reservation</h2>
      <br>
      <p>Call us now to book a table in our restaurant. Calls must be in the same day as the reservation.</p>
      <br>
      <a onclick="sorry()">BOOK A TABLE</a>
    </div>
    <div id="inner-content2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-content-wrapper" class="cf">
    <div id="inner-content3">
    </div>
    <div id="inner-content4" class="cf">
      <h2>Reservation</h2>
      <br>
      <p>Call us now to book a table in our restaurant. Calls must be in the same day as the reservation.</p>
      <br>
      <a onclick="sorry()">BOOK A TABLE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice and helping me. I'm self teaching myself and all the advice I receive, I truly appreciate it.